# How to know if Partition key is working correctly in Cosmos DB

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to create a test Cosmos and am a little confused about partition keys. Specifically what I am worried about is that when I add an item to the container I don't see any value being filled under the partition column.

What I am trying to do is set up a webscraper that would get text values. From that file I am choosing "Source" and "Date" as my partition columns so that I can have a somewhat even partition distribution.

[image]

I then created a Cosmos DB and loaded some test values:

[image]

During set up I wrote (minus the quotes) "/Source/Date" and I assumed that after I upload that item I would see those values be filled in. However, it looks like this test container is looking for one column called "/Source/Date".

I did a test where I only used "Source" as my partition key and it does auto fill in that value:

[image]

Am I missing something here? Can I only have one column as a partition key? If in first screenshot I see that "/Source/News" is empty does that mean that there is no "Partition key"?

I also did another test with having a unique key and it did work where I can't enter duplicate values of "Source/Date", but when I tried to put a comma in the field where the container is asking for a partition key I got an error.

Any help would be helpful.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> From that file I am choosing "Source" and "Date" as my partition
>   columns so that I can have a somewhat even partition distribution.

I believe there's a bit of misunderstanding on your part regarding the partition key.

Currently you can't specify a partition key on two attributes. A partition key can only be created on a single attribute in your JSON document.

When you specify partition key essentially you're specifying a path to the JSON property in the document.

For example, considering you're setting the partition key as `Source/Date`, your document would look something like the following:

```
{
  "id": "your document id",
  "Source": {
    "Date": "some date value"
  },
  "Url": "blah blah",
  "Text": "more blah blah",
  "Formal_Source": "even more blah blah"
}
```

Comment: I see. I believe that is where the confusion was coming from all along. I thought that I could add multiple columns there and then would be able to have the data be spread across based on the source and then also when that source was added.

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Just to add to this I would not use date as a partition key. This will result in a hot partition for the current date.

Comment: Hi @MarkBrown, that is a good point. I think with this web scraping Source would be a good partition (at least better than some alternatives). On a high level all I am doing is going to select what the domain of the source is (CNN, Reddit, ect.) and then get the text. From the schema that I have above I think "Source" would be best option".

Comment: Sure, whatever evenly distributes writes across partition key range is a good choice. Typically in these types of apps like click tracking, etc there is one container for high volume writes and another for queries with a different partition key connected via Change Feed. Whether you do this will depend on the query volume and cost of queries overall.